# How to make same javascript code work on more than one same kind of field?

Tags: javascript

I am using Field collection module and added some repeated fields. Each field has one button, on clicking the button, the text area is expands(toggling kind of). But the java code is working for only first field not for rest of the fields. I have added java script code through .info method. Thanks.

```
(function ($) {
     Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
         attach: function(context, settings) {
            $( "#button1" ).click(function() {
              $( "#p1" ).toggle("slow");
            }); 

 }}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: are you using .each() method?

Comment: i have added the following code by making the .js file in the field collection module folder, it is working fine, but only for the first field, but not for the rest of the fields ...............................(function ($) {
     Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
         attach: function(context, settings) {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      $( "#p" ).toggle("slow");
    }); 
 }}})(jQuery);

Comment: can you paste the code you are using?

Comment: Just have added JS code in the main question..Thx

Comment: one way is to use class for each button and then call $('.class').each(
// and then your code goes.. 
)

Comment: the other fields that are not working on, **do they have the same div ID name?** "#button1" and "#p1" ? oh wait, of course not, ID names can only be used once. You need to use div class instead. (see answ by Erin)

Comment: I have kept same id name for all fields. let me change as shown by the Erin.

Comment: @codenext, name id's are only suppose to be, used once, unique. Use class names instead, those don't have to be unique and can be used as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, this is a kind of tricky one! Because you want the element corresponding to the button you clicked to be the only one that toggles, correct? Not all of the elements?

I think you want something like this for your code, where everything between [] is replaced with the relevant selector. So [BUTTON CLASS] would become the class that you apply to all the buttons, such as "button", not the ID that only gets applied to a single button ("button1", "button2", and so on). Likewise, [CHILD CLASS] would be replaced with a class that you apply to all elements that you have IDs such as "p1", "p2", etc on.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $( ".[BUTTON CLASS]" ).each(function (index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
          $(this).parent().children(".[CHILD CLASS]").toggle("slow");
        });
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Hope that helps!

**Edit**
Updates made to the code to get the button parent and then the #p1 from there. It assumes that the #p1 and the #button1 are both children of the same element.

**Edit 2**
Given the structure

```
<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <ul class="buttonlist">
    <li><button class="button1">Toggle</button></li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="button2">Link</button></a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="p1" style="display:none">Text to be written here</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <ul class="buttonlist">
    <li><button class="button1">Toggle</button></li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="button2">Link</button></a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="p1" style="display:none">Text to be written here</p>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <ul class="buttonlist">
    <li><button class="button1">Toggle</button></li>
    <li><a href="#"><button class="button2">Link</button></a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="p1" style="display:none">Text to be written here</p>
</div>
```

The following JS does what you want, I believe:

```
$( ".button1" ).each(function (index) {
  $(this).click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.buttoncontainer').children(".p1").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: First of thanks for the answers, I tried with several ways but unable to get it done. for better explanation I have created link in JSFIDDLE. For the representation i have three section separated with <hr>. What I want is if I click the first toggle button it has to open its own content. not others. The same concept I am applying for the series of fields which i have created using field collection module, So each field has this toggle button. Note:-I have more than 100 such repeated fields in one content type, so that much buttons. Link-- https://jsfiddle.net/ccodenext/ves02oaj/

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML output? If so, I can make some suggestions that will make this easier; namely, adding a class to the div and moving the <p> tag into the div. If you can change the HTML output, something like this would work: https://jsfiddle.net/oxw1zsn4/

Comment: Hi, your code is working PERFECTLY fine. Thanks. But i found one issue, may be not related to this code, while i added the HTML part in the each field and provided js part in JS folder and css part in CSS folder (which I attached using .info method of adding css and js in field collection module) the js and css part seems not have any effect on content, looks like it is not attached. So, i used Code per Node module for that node and applied your js and css there, IT IS WORKING fine. But i do not know why js and css is not attaching by .info method, which same thing working with CPN. Thx

Comment: You are right, it is affecting the HTML output, because js and css file may be not recognizing the class of html elements. This thing works when I use Code per Node module and add CSS and JS code there. But problem arises when I make Views of that content type,  any suggestion? Very Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, and you have the code surrounded in `(function ($) {Drupal.behaviors.myfunction = {attach: function(context, settings) {}}}`?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to solve this issue since couple of hours & I found following solution (1) For Content_type: If i add the code using Code Per Node, the entire code is working fine (2) For Content_type_View: When I create the Views(I am using Fields not content in views setting as i need fields in my view) of the created content type the Toggle and Link is not working (my be code is not working in views from CPN), so I added the same code in .info file of Views and It is working fine for views. So, now it is what I needed, working fine, Is this ok, please suggestion needed ? continue......

Comment: ........but again if it works through Views module's .info file then why it is not working through field collection module's .info file? Please could you put light on this. Very thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this goes a bit beyond my debugging skillset. You might want to open another question with these details and link back to this one, since it's related to the issue posted about here but not quite the same.